# Common Lisp setf expansions for functions which access bits of integers

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am writing a program in Common Lisp which needs to store a bunch of status bits for a very large number of entries in an array (the whole program is pretty much fortran-in-lisp) and the status bits are encoded as bits in a fixnum sitting in this array.  The accessors for these status bits are actually going to be defined by a macro so I don't have to care about allocating the bits, but a sample reader function might be

```
(defun deadp (e)
  (logbitp 0 e))
```

(In real life this will be inlined and cluttered with declarations to try and make sure it's quick but those don't matter here I think.)

I need these things to be functions because I want to be able to map them, but also because the using-a-macro-to-inline-a-function thing makes me feel bad.

Then I'll be using this as something like this:

```
(defconstant status-index 3)
...
(dotimes (i nentries)
  (unless (deadp (aref entries i status-index))
    ...))
```

(In real life `(aref entries i status-index)` will be `(status entries i)`, which in turn is going to need a `setf` method but I think that's easy.)

or

```
(loop for i below nentries
      counting (if (deadp entries i status-index) 1 0))
```

And of course there will be other similar single-bit flags which will have different bits associated with them.

So, now I want to be able to do this:

```
(dotimes (i nentries)
  ...
  (when ...
    (setf (deadp (aref entries i status-index) t)))
  ...)
```

which should turn into code equivalent to

```
(dotimes (i nentries)
  ...
  (when ...
    (progn 
      (setf (ldb (byte 1 0) (aref entries i status-index)) 1)
      t))
  ...)
```

And also this:

```
(let ((status 0))
  ...
  (when ...
    (setf (deadp status) t))
  ...)
```

which should turn into code equivalent to this:

```
(let ((status 0))
  ...
  (when ...
    (progn
      (setf (ldb (byte 1 0) status) 1)
      t))
  ...)
```

In other words I want my `deadp` function to be an accessor and for `setf` on it to work in a general way for it: `(setf (deadp (cdr x)) nil)` should work, etc.

So this has dropped me into bits of CL that I've avoided for a long time: defining `setf` expanders.  Pretty obviously just defining a `(setf deadp)` function won't work because numbers are immutable, and I'm *fairly* sure that `defsetf` is not powerful enough, so I need `define-setf-expander`, which I don't understand.

Can someone explain how I need to do this?  I think the particular `deadp` function is not critical, although all the functions I care about will look like variants of it.

---

An alternative answer would be 'that's a braindead approach, instead do ...', and I'm open to those.  I have considered writing code which abstracts the array away, so instead of `(deadp (aref ...))` I'd write `(deadp people ...)` where `people` is the array of people.  This would be fine, and it's easy to see how to make that `setf`able, except I also want to be able to say `(deadp status)` where `status` is just a fixnum.  But perhaps there is some better approach.

Comment: Not so much an answer but a "possible alternate approach". How much slowdown would using a bit-vector give you? How much more memory? At least SBCL implements them efficiently.

Comment: @Vatine: I'm using a bit vector currently in fact!  This is the wrong place to describe what I'm trying to do but by storing information in elements in a fixnum array I hope to be able to use a specialised array rather than either a general array or (as I'm not doing) two arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the SBCL documentation for GET-SETF-EXPANSION, a setf expander must:
"Return five values needed by the SETF machinery: a list of temporary
variables, a list of values with which to fill them, a list of temporaries
for the new values, the setting function, and the accessing function."
The setting function and accessing function are actually just the forms that set and access the value at the place, not function objects.

Try this:

```
(define-setf-expander deadp (place)
  (let ((new (gensym)))
    (values nil nil (list new)
            `(progn (setf (ldb (byte 1 0) ,place) (if ,new 1 0))
                    ,new)
            `(deadp ,place))))
```

Sample expansion:

```
(let ((status 1))
  (setf (deadp status) t))
->
(let ((status 1))
  (LET* ((#:G605 T))
    (SETF (LDB (BYTE 1 0) STATUS)
            (IF #:G605
                1
                0))
    #:G605))
```

Comment: I think that's it.  I'm still not sure I understand (in fact I'm sure I don't understand!) `define-setf-expander` properly, but this seems to work.  Let me try to make my code use it so I can check properly: if it does I'll accept the answer later on.  Thank you.